# Hide LeftViewController or RightViewController with JASidePanels

Tags: ios, objective-c, jasidepanels

I have implemented [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) using storyboards in my project.

`LeftViewController`, `CenterViewController` and `RightViewController` have the same Custom Class "`myViewController`" in Identity Inspector, I can add functionallity to the buttons inside of them which code resides in `myViewController.m`, code needs to be in `myViewController.m`

The problem is when I need to check if an `elementX` in `CenterViewController` is visible, it always return `Hidden = No` even if the `elementX` in `CenterViewController` is visible and also I want to know how to implement a `[self showCenterPanelAnimated:animated];` inside `myViewController.m` where I can show/hide panels when a button inside `LeftViewController` or `RightViewController` is pressed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For second part of your question

> I want to know how to implement a [self
>   showCenterPanelAnimated:animated]; inside myViewController.m where I
>   can show/hide panels when a button inside LeftViewController or
>   RightViewController is pressed.

Please import `JASidePanelController.h` and `UIViewController+JASidePanel.h` in your file and add the line below on button click to show center panel.

```
[self.sidePanelController showCenterPanelAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try, this code goes in `myViewController.m` or `MySidePanelController.m`?

Comment: You need to add the line in the file from where you want to show center panel.

Comment: Awesome! worked like a charm, if you have a link where you found this answer or documentation can you provide it please? Thank you!

Comment: Its there in GitHub page of JASidePanels :)